# gitlab clone as another user

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a project from another user, but I cannot. 
I'm not asked for login and password.

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

error:

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
```

Comment: The title says gitlab, but your clone url points to github - which one is it?

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: _“I'm not asked for login and password.”_ This is correct if you provide them in URL.

Answer (score -1):

Solution found:
You need to go to:
Control Panel \ User Accounts and Family Security \ Credential Manager
in the section: "General credentials" delete the register for git. It looks like this: git: https: //github.com
At the next interaction in the console, git will ask to enter the login and password in a separate authorization window.

Comment: What Control Panel? GitLab? GitHub? Windows?

Comment: Won't this clobber login credentials being used for your other projects?